# How to remove the last slash in an URL with htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove the last slash of my URLs.

I put this in my htaccess file :

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works with files hosted in the root (or pages generated from the database), but it doesn't work with files hosted in subdirectories.

For example, I would like that this :

```
 http://mywebsite.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/index.php
```

goes to that :

```
 http://mywebsite.com/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

but it goes to that :

```
 http://mywebsite.com/[homeserver]/[server]/www/dir1/dir2/dir3
```

What is wrong with my htaccess file ?

Edit : here is the entire htaccess file

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

### Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

### Get the URL in pathinfo mode
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php/$1

### Redirect index.php to the root
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://mywebsite.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add add below rule after `RewriteEngine` On and provide your full `.htaccess` for further analysis.

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: I've just provided the full .htaccess, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

### Remove www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]

### Redirect index.php from anywhere
# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]

### Get the URL in pathinfo mode
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the URL without a `/` at the end is redirected to the URL with a `/` at the end. I would like it in the other way...

Comment: That's not happening with these rules. Did you clear you browser cache? Also tell what URL did you use for testing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in `.htacccess` file to remove slash at the end of URL.

```
# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

I have used this and working fine.